# How can I copy the installer to the temp file and then run it?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to copy the installer to the temp folder and then run it from that location.

This is what I am trying to do, but so far to no avail.

```pascal
FileCopy(ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'), ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Setup.exe'), True);
Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Setup.exe'), '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
```

How can I copy the installer to the temp file and then run it from the code section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why, but there's an explicit check that prevents [`FileCopy` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_filecopy) from copying the installer itself.

See a [`PathCompare` check in `FileCopy` branch of `CmnFunc2Proc` in `ScriptFunc_R.pas`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-6_0_4-2/Projects/ScriptFunc_R.pas#L529-L535):

```pascal
end else if Proc.Name = 'FILECOPY' then begin
  ExistingFilename := Stack.GetString(PStart-1);
  if PathCompare(ExistingFilename, SetupLdrOriginalFilename) <> 0 then
    Stack.SetBool(PStart, CopyFileRedir(ScriptFuncDisableFsRedir,
      ExistingFilename, Stack.GetString(PStart-2), Stack.GetBool(PStart-3)))
  else
    Stack.SetBool(PStart, False);
```

*I do not know what is the reason for this, but there probably is some. So beware, you might be doing something that the installer does not like.*

---

You can of course workaround that by calling [Windows `copy` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy):

```pascal
Exec(
  ExpandConstant('{cmd}'),
  Format('/C copy "%s" "%s"', [ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'), ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Setup.exe')]),
  '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

---

Or you can implement a replacement function with use of [`TFileStream` class](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TFileStream):

```pascal
function FileCopyUnrestricted(const ExistingFile, NewFile: String): Boolean;
var
  Buffer: string;
  Stream: TFileStream;
  Size: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  try
    Stream := TFileStream.Create(ExistingFile, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
    try
      Size := Stream.Size;
      SetLength(Buffer, Size div 2 + 1);
      Stream.ReadBuffer(Buffer, Size);
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;

  if Result then
  begin
    try
      Stream := TFileStream.Create(NewFile, fmCreate);
      try
        Stream.WriteBuffer(Buffer, Size);
      finally
        Stream.Free;
      end;
    except
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

*This is an inefficient implementation that loads whole file to memory. If your installer is large, you will have to improve the code to copy the file in chunks.*

*The code is for Unicode version of Inno Setup (the only version as of Inno Setup 6).*