# How to append new content in existing text file in Inno Setup

Tags: node.js, logging, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have enabled the installation log in Inno Setup using `SetupLogging = yes`.

It is creating a log file temp directory and I'm copying that log to my program data:

```pascal
procedure DeinitializeSetup();    
var  
  logfilepathname, newfilepathname: string;  
begin  
  logfilepathname := ExpandConstant('{log}');  
  newfilepathname := 'ProgramData\InstallerlogFile'
 
  FileCopy(logfilepathname, newfilepathname, false);  
end;
```

Every time I create a new installer it replaces the content of the older file in program data. I wanted to append new log content instead of replacing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to append not-too-huge contents from one file to another is using [`LoadStringFromFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_loadstringfromfile) and [`SaveStringToFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_savestringtofile):

```pascal
var
  S: AnsiString;
begin
  if LoadStringFromFile(logfilepathname, S) then
    SaveStringToFile(newfilepathname, S, True); // True = append
end;
```

---

Or you can just execute [`copy` "cmd" command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy) using [`Exec`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec), when "dest" exists already (if not, use your `FileCopy` code):

```
copy [/b] <dest> + <source>
```

---

But that won't work for the log, as it is locked by the installer proces. To read a locked file, you need to resort to more low-level functions. You can use [`TFileStream`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TFileStream) with its `fmShareDenyNone`.

For an example, see `FileCopyUnrestricted` in my answer to
[How can I copy the installer to the temp file and then run it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34206377/850848)

To make it append, replace the

```pascal
Stream := TFileStream.Create(NewFile, fmCreate);
```

with

```pascal
if not FileExists(NewFile) then Mode := fmCreate
  else Mode := fmOpenWrite;
Stream := TFileStream.Create(NewFile, Mode);
Stream.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
```

- `Mode` is `Word` variable
- Once you are using `TFileStream`, you can optimize the code not to load whole contents to memory at once, in case you need it. You do not, for the log file, as it is not too huge.